# Delete files and exclude some with find

Tags: linux, shell, bash-scripting

It was an old problem. I knew how to delete files and exclude some, like this:

```
rm `find ~/temporary/Test\ 1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1|grep -v 'A'`
```

but the problem is the folder 'Test 1' containing a space in name, the result of find was

```
/home/owner/temporary/Test 1/B
```

It makes `rm` error, how can I fix it?

Comment: Thanks, but my most annoying problem is spaces and other special character are in the file names, those methods can't fix it. And I don't know how to search for this problem :-(

Comment: Don't try to parse the output of `find` or `ls`. They were not meant to have their output parsed, because `find` can work on files directly: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Okay, maybe I understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works even with spaces but requires some typing:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name "peter" ! -name "paul & mary" -exec rm {} \+
```

Or with newer `find` versions (findutils >= 4.2.3):

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name "peter" ! -name "paul & mary" -delete
```

Comment: The `-print0 | xargs -0` version isn't needed. You can call `-exec rm {} \+` directly, which would be more efficient.

Comment: @slhck Thanks, I updated my answer. Although the efficiency is questionable because `xargs` would lead to fewer `rm` calls :)

Comment: Thanks scai! It works. When I saw these answers, I realized that they are simple, maybe I need to read more manuals.

Comment: I read it twice but somehow I managed to fail to noticed it. Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

```
$ mkdir -p temp\ 1/sub\ 1
$ touch temp\ 1/{one,two,three} temp\ 1/sub\ 1/{one,two,three}
$ tree temp\ 1/
temp\ 1/
├── one
├── sub\ 1
│   ├── one
│   ├── three
│   └── two
├── three
└── two

1 directory, 6 files
$ find temp\ 1/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f ! -regex '.*/.*o.*' -exec rm -v {} \;
removed ‘temp 1/three’
```

So the key concepts here are:

1. The `-regex` filter with negation (`!` before option) and the pattern that is **applied to the whole path** of the found file.
2. The `-exec` command that has the `{}` token replaced with properly quoted path. Remember to add the `\;` to mark the end of the command line.